# comparing parameters from different models

Tags: logit, poisson-regression

I have the following two models, for $i=1,...,N$ sites, and covariate $x$ ~ $ U(-1,1)$:

1. $\log(A_i) = \alpha + \beta  x_i$
2. $\text{logit}(B_i) = \gamma+ \delta  x_i$,

where $A_i = B_i  M$, where M is fixed and could be any non-negative positive integer (e.g. M=400).

I want to derive alpha and beta parameters knowing gamma and delta. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. If you have access to the data set, i.e. $A_i,B_i$, then simply regress $A_i=m B_i+e_i$, and obtain the estimate $m$ of your M.

Comment: I have only access to data for estimating $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and thus $A$. I wonder if I can then derive $\gamma$ and $\delta$ from $\alpha$ and $\beta$. E.g. Is the following relationship valid? $\gamma = \text{logit}(\exp(\alpha) \, M)$. How can I derive $\delta$?